# How to reduce Waiting TTFB time on GET request to database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, axios, get-request, page-load-time

I am having problems with my Axios GET requests taking up to 3-7 seconds to retrieve the data from my Firebase Cloud Firestore Database. I have tried searching up page optimization techniques to speed up my page load such as cacheing resources or image optimization but nothing is helping with the actual request time. The image below is for 1 GET request which pulls an array of objects from the database. It's not as if it's a large array though, there is only 6 objects currently in it and it still takes very long to retrieve. This happens for all of my get requests and I'm not sure why.

It isn't only on initial page load, it still takes a couple seconds (generally 2-5 on subsequent loads) to load in even after refreshing the page or moving between pages on my site. It's not consistent at all and I was wondering if there was anything I can do to improve the request speed.

[image: Image evidence]

The Action for the "posts" request above. I am using React Redux to get the json data from Firebase Database and adding it to my store:

```
// get all posts
export const getPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
   axios
     .get("/posts")
     .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
           type: SET_POSTS,
           payload: res.data,
        });
      })
.catch(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_POSTS,
    payload: [],
  });
});
};
```

The reducer:

> ```
> export default function (state = initialState, action) {
> switch (action.type) {
> case SET_POSTS:
>   return {
>     ...state,
>     posts: action.payload,
>     loading: false,
>   };
>   default:
>      return state;
>    }
>  }
> ```

Firebase functions:

```
// fetch all posts
exports.getAllPosts = (req, res) => {
   db.collection("posts")
     .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
     .get()
     .then(data => {
        let posts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
           posts.push({
              postId: doc.id,
              body: doc.data().body,
              userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
              createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
              commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
              likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
              userImage: doc.data().userImage
           });
         });
         return res.json(posts);
         })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
     };
```

Another example of my GET request to retrieve user data after login:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using the JavaScript SDK on one hand and the REST API on the other hand? Any specific reason for not usinf the JavaScript SDK for all you queries (read and write) to Firestore?

Comment: How often is the content changing?